# How to find all occurrences and all position of a substring in a string?

Tags: c, string, char, substring

I need to find all occurrences and output all positions of a substring in a string.

For example: my string is `abaaab`, my substring is `aa`, position is `3` and `4`, because in `aaa` my substr is repeated twice.

I want the position at the end to be printed from right to left, and after the position of substring I want the number of occurrences of my subtring.

I tried to do it and I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *str, c;
    int x = 0, y = 1;

    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    printf("Inserisci stringa principale : ");

        while (c != '\n') {
        // read the input from keyboard standard input
        c = getc(stdin);

        // re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
        str = (char*)realloc(str, y * sizeof(char));

        // store read character by making pointer point to c
        str[x] = c;

        x++;
        y++;
        }

    str[x] = '\0'; // at the end append null character to mark end of string

    printf("\nLa stringa inserita : %s", str);

      char *sub, b;
      int w = 0, z = 1;

      sub = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

      printf("Immetti sottostringa da cercare : ");

          while (b != '\n') {
            // read the input from keyboard standard input
            b = getc(stdin);

            // re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
            sub = (char*)realloc(sub, z * sizeof(char));

            // store read character by making pointer point to c
            sub[w] = b;

            w++;
            z++;
          }

      sub[w] = '\0'; // at the end append null character to mark end of string

    char *p1, *p2, *p3;
    int i=0,j=0,flag=0;

      p1 = str;
      p2 = sub;

      for(i = 0; i<strlen(str); i++)
      {
        if(*p1 == *p2)
          {
              p3 = p1;
              for(j = 0;j<strlen(sub);j++)
              {
                if(*p3 == *p2)
                {
                  p3++;p2++;
                } 
                else
                  break;
              }
              p2 = sub;
              if(j == strlen(sub))
              {
                 flag = 1;
                printf("\nSottostringa trovata all'indice : %d\n",i);
              }
          }
        p1++; 
      }
      if(flag==0)
      {
           printf("Sottostringa non trovata");
      }
    free(str);
    free(sub);
    return (0);
    }
```

But it only shows me the position of the first occurrence, and not the number of occurrences.

Comment: A trivial way would be to use `strstr` in a loop; Or is it an exercise which does not allow you to use `strstr`?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- Your string reallocation scheme is incorrect: the space allocated is one byte too short for the string and you never test for memory allocation failure.  You could use `getline()` if your system supports it or at least write a function to factorize the code.
- `c` is unsinitialized the first time you loop test `c != '\n'`: this has undefined behavior.
- Your matching algorithm is too complicated: you use both index values and moving pointers. Use one or the other.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* read an allocated string from stream.
   stop at newline, not included in string.
   Return NULL upon EOF
 */
char *my_getline(FILE *stream) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t pos = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getc(stream)) != EOF) {
        char *newp = realloc(line, pos + 2);
        if (newp == NULL) {
            free(line);
            return NULL;
        }
        line = newp;
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        line[pos++] = (char)c;
    }
    if (line) {
        line[pos] = '\0';
    }
    return line;
}

int main(void) {
    char *str, *sub;
    size_t len1, len2, i, count = 0;

    // type the main string
    printf("Inserisci stringa principale :\n");
    str = my_getline(stdin);

    // type the substring to search for
    printf("Immetti sottostringa da cercare :\n");
    sub = my_getline(stdin);

    if (str && sub) {
        len1 = strlen(str);
        len2 = strlen(sub);
        for (i = 0; i + len2 <= len1; i++) {
            if (!memcmp(str + i, sub, len2)) {
                count++;
                // substring found at offset
                printf("Sottostringa trovata all'indice : %zu\n", i);
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            // substring not found
            printf("Sottostringa non trovata\n");
        }
    }
    free(str);
    free(sub);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- The above code finds matches for the empty substring at every offset in the search string. Whether matches should be found or not is a question of specification, but this behavior is consistent with that of `strstr()`.
- you could also use standard function `strstr()` to locate the matches.

Here is a version of the main loop using `strstr()`:

```
if (str && sub) {
    for (char *p = str; (p = strstr(p, sub)) != NULL; p++) {
        count++;
        // substring found at offset
        printf("Sottostringa trovata all'indice : %tu\n", p - str);
        if (*p == '\0')  /* special case for the empty string */
            break;
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        // substring not found
        printf("Sottostringa non trovata\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've checked you code and it seems that your code has problem in the line

```
if(j == strlen(sub))
```

Since j is starting from 0 it will always be 1 less than the length of the sub string, change your code to

```
if(j+1 == strlen(sub))
```

and it should solve your problem.

For number of occurrences you need another variable to count whenever there is a match with the substring, modifying the if block

```
if(j+1 == strlen(sub))
{
      flag = 1;
      occurrences+=1;  //declare variable occurrences and initialize it to 0
      printf("\nSottostringa trovata all'indice : %d\n",i);
}
```

Then after the end of the loop just print the 'occurrences' to get the desired result.

Also this is not an efficient way to solve the problem, you can refer to

https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/introduction-to-string-searching-algorithms/

for better approach.

Comment: How can I first show the right position? For example if the string is aaaooaaoodf and the substring is aa instead of 0 1 5 get 5 1 0?

Comment: push the index into a stack and then pop them one by one after the end of the loop.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean, I as output I need to get the variable occurrences first, but if the mold in the loop is printed every time, and if the mold out is printed as the last thing, and then the position but from the last At first, with my code how can i do it?

Comment: okay a simpler way would be to do a reverse for loop,in your scenario change the outer loop to  for(i = strlen(l)-1; i>=0; i--) and instead of p1++ perform p1--, as well as point p1 to last index of the array before the loop starts, keeping the rest of the code same you will get your result.

Comment: what i suggested before was to use stack data structure for the purpose, incase you don't know about stacks refer https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

A trivial way of finding each occurrence is a `strstr` called in a loop. After each match, let `strstr` search one position after that where the match has been found:

```
int main( ) {

    const char *string = "abaaab";
    const char *toSearch = "aa";
    int nrOfOccurences = 0;
    printf("searching for occurences of '%s' in string '%s':\n", string, toSearch);
    const char* pos = string;
    while (pos) {
        pos = strstr(pos, toSearch);
        if (pos) {
            printf("found occurence at position %td\n", pos-string);
            nrOfOccurences++;
            pos++;  // skip one character
        }
    }
    nrOfOccurences = findRecursive(string, toSearch, 0,0);
    printf("nr of occurences: %d\n", nrOfOccurences);
    return 0;
}
```

If you need - as somehow stated - to print the occurrences starting from the last one, you could use a recursive function like the following. A comment in the code above shows how to use it:

```
int findRecursive(const char* str, const char* toSearch, ptrdiff_t pos, int nrOfOccurences) {

    char *next = strstr(str, toSearch);
    if (next) {
        ptrdiff_t foundPos = pos + next - str;
        nrOfOccurences = findRecursive(next+1, toSearch, foundPos+1, nrOfOccurences+1);
        printf("occurence found at position %td\n", foundPos);
    }
    return nrOfOccurences;
}
```

Comment: `pos-string` is of type `ptrdiff_t` so the format specifier should be `"%td"`

Comment: @Govind Parmar: right, thanks. Adapted the answer accordingly.